# Active Record model having relationship to 2 instances of the same class

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm working on an application that allows users to generate university schedules and then edit them side-by-side with a friend.

The following 3 models exist in the app:

```
User
 - has_many schedules
 - has_many sidebysides

Schedule
 - belongs_to user
 - has_many sidebysides

SideBySide
 - belongs_to user1
 - belongs_to user2
 - belongs_to schedule1
 - belongs_to schedule2
```

The parent-child relationships look as follows:

```
User IS PARENT OF schedules, sidebysides
Schedule IS PARENT OF sidebysides AND IS CHILD OF user
SideBySide IS CHILD OF user1, user2, schedule1, schedule2
```

I have a feeling I'm approaching this wrong. How might I create the relationships explained above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
belongs_to :user1, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :user2, :class_name => "User"
```

You can't do `belongs_to user1` since `user1` is an instance of `User`. Same applies to Schedules

Comment: I thought it might be something along these lines. I'll try this out and see if it works.